# How to find directories without dot in bash?

Tags: bash, find

I try to find folders without dot symbol. 
I Search it in users directory via this script:

```
!#/bin/bash

users=$(ls /home)

for user in $users;

do

find /home/$user/web/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname '*' ! -iname "*.*"

done
```

But I see in result users with folders with dot, for example - test.uk or test.cf

What I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean `$user` is `test.uk`? `-iname` only tests the final name in the pathname, not the whole pathname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find` with `-regex` option for that:

```
find /home/$user/web/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '\./[^.]*$'
```

`'\./[^.]*$'` will match names without any DOT.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your command finds directories in `/home/username/web/` where the directory doesn't contain a dot.

It does not check to see if `username` itself contains a dot.

To see if there's a dot anywhere, you can use `ipath` instead of `iname`:

```
!#/bin/bash
users=$(ls /home)
for user in $users;
do
find /home/$user/web/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname '*' ! -ipath "*.*"
done
```

Or more correctly and succinctly:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/*/web/ -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -ipath "*.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for find; just use an extended glob to match any files not containing a `.`

```
shopt -s extglob
for dir in /home/*/;
do
    printf '%s\n' "$dir"/!(*.*)
done
```

You could even do away with the loop entirely:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' /home/*/!(*.*)
```

To exclude directories in `/home` that contain a `.`, you can change `/home/*/` to `/home/!(*.*)/` in either example.

Comment: I was just about to post a solution with `+([^.])`.